# Windows 7 RTM 32Bit vs 64Bit (with 4GB RAM)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory, 32-bit

I just upgraded to 64Bit Win 7 RTM - very happy with it - I also have 4GB RAM. 
The problem is I bought an expensive Logitech Wireless USB Headset, that sounds really choppy in a 64Bit system - it uses generic usb audio driver from Microsoft.

I am thinking of using the 32Bit version of Windows 7 instead, to solve this problem.

Do you think I'll lose a lot of performance if I lose .5GB ram and miss out on 64bit?

Been trying for days to get the headset working , and no solution exists yet to fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stick with the 64bit. 32bit is a dying breed. There is no doubt in my mind that Logitech supports 64bit. Make sure you have their latest official drivers installed.

That .5gb of ram may not seem like much now, but you will be kicking yourself later for reverting to 32bit.

Comment: Logitech state they're working hard on producing drivers for Win7, but... this device doesn't need a driver it hooks into an OS supplied driver. So Logitech support just say - your device uses a feature of the OS. 

Not even sure if its an issue with the USB Audio driver, but its something, and I doubt if MS are even aware of the problem. Even if they were do you really think they would fix it for the few users of  1 product?

Comment: But yeah... I know what you mean... Really liking the smooth performance of my system, besides this audio issue.

Comment: I see what you mean. You'll regret going back to 32bit, though. I would focus more on getting the proper drivers or a workaround to your problem. I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: You have a point... Wonder what the problem can be with that device....

Comment: Not sure. I would post a specific question here and on the official (and unofficial) Windows 7 boards. You should be able to get a lot of help.

Comment: Go with 64bit; thedude19 really has a valid point!

Comment: Guys - fixed the problem... 64Bit rocks... a note to mention here: Its all too easy to start blaming 64Bit, when maybe its a small problem, you can fix and identify....

Comment: Great to hear you fixed your problem! I saw you answered your other question. That was a very weird fix indeed :)

Comment: That's great! And yea, 64bit is very easy to blame. But don't worry, it wasn't long ago at all that 64bit was barely supported by manufacturers. Huge strides have been made in the last year or 2 it seems. Congrats on getting your problem fixed and enjoy you sweet headphones on your 64bit machine :)

Comment: Over a year later and I was reviewing this question. I don't think I'll ever go back to 32bit computing, not even for nostalgic reasons.

Comment: Definitely. 64 bit is not the future anymore, it's the present.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite an informative article on the subject. A couple years old, but i learnt a few things :

http://www.dansdata.com/askdan00015.htm

Please post or comment if you have better ones

Answer (score 1):

I lost 1 GB just by sticking with Vista 32bit on one PC. If possible, always choose the 64bit version of the OS.

A lot of apps are starting to get 64bit versions which are normally faster, the OS feels more stable and you can actually access all your RAM.

Comment: 1GB thats a lot.. thats like 1/4 of a typical 4GB setup.... can't be good...

Comment: Actually, I had 2 GB of RAM in my PC. Today I bought 4 more; the PC I'm using is going to be used by my parents, so I figured 32bit Vista was ok for them. Today, when I put the additional RAM in the PC (I just wanted to test them out), Vista showed me I had 6 GB of RAM  and Task Manager showed me I had 3096 MB of usable RAM. That really put a dent in my morale.

Comment: @alex, thats heavy stuff dude. thats 1/2 loss ratio... I wish 32Bit would just perish already....

Comment: Me too! I'm not that worried, though. The RAM was put in just for testing; I was expecting that to happen. But it's still a shock to see such a thing. A lot of people won't know where their RAM went. And a lot of vendors offered PCs with 4GB of RAM and a 32 bit OS. I'd be pretty pissed off if that would happen to me.

Answer (score 1):

i recently purchased gigabyte GA EQ45M-S2 (supports upto 16 GB RAM) and i am happy with Win 7 x64 with 8 GB  (2*4gb).I dual boot xp and win 7 (both x64)and believe me i will never ever be using 32 bits. 
Very soon i will be upgrading it further to full 16 GB,as required by the work i do.........
For now enjoying Win 7 x64........................  :)

And just stick with x64.We r gonna see a hell of driver support soon....... and we are alrady having :)

Cheers !

Comment: I couldn't agree more, I am loving Win 7 64bit. The best all round windows computing experience I have ever had, and I've been around from the beginning, pre PC days, had every MS OS. 

I also like Linux, but unfortunately I can't use it as main OS, because I am a Windows developer.