# adding additional RAM without reinstalling windows

Tags: windows, memory, 64-bit

I bought a laptop with 4GB RAM. Im planning to upgrade it to 8GB later (not in a short time) but i dont want to waste my time in reinstalling windows (if possible).

So, i think i will install windows 64bit for now, with a hope that i dont have to reinstall my windows when i upgrade my RAM to 8GB.

My questions are :

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it good to have 64bit windows running on 4GB RAM?Does having 64bit on 4GB RAM effect laptop's performance?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/35110/windows-7-rtm-32bit-vs-64bit-with-4gb-ram?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like jack said above, you can install 64 bit windows only if your system is a 64-bit one. as for the ram, installing 4 more gb of ram on your 64-bit laptop will make it way more faster in terms of performance. and you dont have to reinstall windows after installing ram. just add the ram in the slot and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks. So, just make things clear...i dont have to reinstall windows & its programs when i add new RAM in 64bit system right?

Comment: @BlazeTama - Of course you don't.  A little search on the subject would have told you that.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just upgrading RAM you can do that without problems.
Also you can run 4 GB of RAM ONLY on 64 bit, you'd be stuck with 3GB otherwise.